# Using a Service Account with delegated credentials to access Google Drive resources shared with a Group

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts, google-groups

I'm trying to use a service account with delegated credentials to access resources in Google Drive that have been shared with a Google Group the impersonated user is a member of. Despite the user having access to the resources, the resources are not visible to the service account.

The service account can access files within our organization (of course), files that are publicly viewable, and files that are explicitly shared with the impersonated user.

How can I use a service account to access files shared with a Google Group?

I gave a Google Group access to a Google Drive resource. I then used a service account to impersonate a member of that Group and attempted to access the shared Drive resource. The resource was invisible to the service account, returning an API response as if the file had not been shared.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you said _"I'm trying to use a service account with delegated credentials to access resources in Google Drive that have been shared with a Google Group the impersonated user is a member of"_, do you mean that the service account is already a member of the Google Group that the files have been shared with?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 the service account is not a member of the Google Group. The user that the service account is impersonating _is_ a member of that Google Group.